# Alpha Emission in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, transparency, emission

it's my first time posting :)

I have a question about increasing the brightness emission of an alpha channel using the cycles renderer.

I have tried different nodes (including the math node) to increase the emission, but no luck. I managed to achieve the desired effect in Eevee, but can't seem to work it out in Cycles.

I found this thread: https://developer.blender.org/D4971#change-39K48buuDDXW
Where emission strength value has been added to the Principled BSDF, but have no idea how to add this to my Blender.. (complete beginner)

Hope someone can guide me in the right direction,

Thanks!
Chris.

EDIT: Tried attaching a screenshot, but there are issues, can also be viewed here: https://ibb.co/DG3KLzZ

[image: Screenshot]

UPDATE: Extra info

When I add a multiplier node between the content colour output and BSDF Emission input, it works it brightening the emission, however it turns the content black and white.

[image: Screencapture of multiplier shader node]

Comment: Assuming the alpha is _encoded_, it would be a trivial multiply. I may be misunderstanding your question however. Blender alpha handling is a mess however, and there are many pinch points. In theory, using an EXR or native render as a source, it will be a simple multiply.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply, i've added an extra screenshot, showing the what happens when I add a multiplier node. It is successful in increasing the emission output, however the colour is rendered black and white...

Comment: That, I believe, is because the multiply node is only for single channel values. You’d need the equivalent of a mix node, or split the three light channels apart and multiply each, then recombine.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I separated the RGB values, multiplied them then combined them again and it worked! I imagined there would be a more straight forward way to do this.. I appreciate your help :)